# CSS width in HTML5 section and input tags

Tags: css, html, width

I have the following HTML5 and CSS code:

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

input {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width:100px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Regular text here!" />
    <input type="number" placeholder="This is a number" />
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Your phone here."/>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your email here." />
  
    <input type="submit" />
  
  </form>
</section>
```

Although the width in the section and input tags are the same (200px) the blue color in the section background does not fully encompass the inputs. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because initially there is a `border`, which is added around the `input` element. You could use `box-sizing: border-box` to force the `border` inside the assigned `width`.

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit] {
  width:100px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Regular text here!" />
    <input type="number" placeholder="This is a number" />
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Your phone here."/>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your email here." />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: How common is the use of this property? Is it advisible to put it in a css reset?

Comment: @PedroPinheiro - It is very much common and Yes, it is advisable.